# Transferring data back to the root ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

in my iOS app the user navigates using a navigation controller.
The user navigates using different UITableViewController.

UIViewController - UITableViewController - UITableViewController

After the user has selected an item in the "last" UITableViewController I am using the following call to return to the root view controller:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) }
```

How can I send data back to the root controller? Previously I used notifications, but I really dislike this concept. Is there a more elegant way?
Should every single UIViewController on the view-stack implement his own callback which is initialized using the

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

method?

How can this be implemented elegantly?

Comment: Are you using segues? If so use an unwind segue and you can pass the data back by accessing the table view controller instance from the unwind method.

Comment: If possible, you should modify your data model, and after returning to the first view controller it should update its appearance based on new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using segues, you could create an unwind segue and use it instead of popToRootViewController. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW8) you can see how to create an unwind segue.

Otherwise, based on your hierarchy, before popToRootViewController, you could access your view controller like this:

```
if let rootVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? YourViewControllerClass {
    rootVC.someProperty = dataToPass
}
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```